# Edit row in EXTJS grid on clicking edit button with a new window opened for editing the fields

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am working on a EXTJS application, where I am displaying data in an EXTJS grid.

There is an edit button against each row. Please check the image.

I want on clicking the edit link, a pop window will open with all the editable fields and I can edit the row from there.

Please help me achieving this.

[image: Grid View]

Here is my code.

```
{
    xtype:'actioncolumn',
    width:50,
    items: [{
        icon: 'assets/images/edit.png',  // Use a URL in the icon config
        tooltip: 'Edit',
        handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
            var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
            alert("Edit " + rec.get('ID'));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not gonna do the coding for you, but here's what you'll need:

- A [window](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.window.Window) with a [form panel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel).
- The [loadRecord](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-loadRecord) method on the form panel's underlying [basic form](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic) to the load record into the form
- The [getValues](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-getValues) method on the basic form to retrieve the modified values
- The [set](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-set) method on the record to write back the values from the form to the record

Answer (score 2):

after click the button( you get the id of the row/record), you can open a window which contain a form grid, then load the data into the form.